# turicreate visualizing decision tree

Tags: visualization, decision-tree, turi-create

Having performed this in turicreate in jupyter noteboopk:

```
small_model = turicreate.decision_tree_classifier.create(train_data,
                                                         validation_set=None,
                                                         target = target,
                                                         features = features,
                                                         max_depth = 2)
```

I am unclear what the visualization route is.

I use this package which uses other modules.

But if I try sklearn, then it looks like the whole process must be in sklearn, as an example. That is not what I want. Looking for an add on that accepts this output as input. But may be that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. You need to write a python routine to print the decision tree in an awkward manner.